# Openvpn multiple instances get single status

Tags: openvpn, ubuntu-14.04, ubuntu-16.04

I Have multiple instances of OpenVPN running. In Ubuntu 14.04 we could control
and get status by using

```
/etc/init.d/openvpn status server4
```

which returns one of these outputs:

```
"* VPN 'server4' is running" OR "* VPN 'server4' is not running"
```

witch gives me an exit code of 0 or 1.

How do I get this to work in Ubuntu 16.04?

Answer (score 0):

`SystemV` worked on old versions of Ubuntu, Debian and Centos Linux operating systems. Now `Systemd` is used. New command is:

```
systemctl status openvpn@server4.service
```

Comment: I Know this is the way to go in the new Ubuntu. The problem is, this does not give me the same output...

Comment: You don't have another way. Check Ubuntu version.